# Can I Copy/Paste the files inside an Azure container instance (Windows) to an external storage?

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances

I am trying to containerize my existing application (.net) on Azure. I want to be able to make changes to my web.config file, once the application has been hosted on a container without needing to rebuild the whole image. The images I use will be Windows-based docker images. As per the documentation available online, Azure file shares are not supported directly for Windows-based instances, is there a workaround which I can use?

Comment: Use Docker volumes to supply configuration. These are lets say shared directories between host and container

Comment: @grapes Can I use Docker volumes on an Azure infrastructure? Can you please share some documentation? I was able to do this on my local machine, however, not sure how to do this on Azure.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/persistent-data-volumes/

Comment: Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the persist volume in ACI is just available with the Linux. So it seems if your ACI is Windows-based you cannot use the persist volume for it, at least now.

For Windows-based container with the persist volume, I suggest you can create Azure Windows VM and run Docker on it. Then you can also create Windows-based container with the persist volume.

And you can [mount the Azure File Share to the Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) and then create volume in it, in the end, create your Windows-based container with the volume. See the sample [Working with Windows Containers and Docker: Save the Data](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/containerization/working-windows-containers-docker-save-data/).

Comment: Thanks, not quite exactly what I am looking for but still gives me a new angle to work on. I think this is the closest I'll get considering the corrent container limitaions on Azure

Comment: OK, I hope you can share the solution if you figure it out. I'm also curious about copying files from Windows in ACI :).